# Iterating over two arrays simultaneously in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, methods

I am doing a project where the end result must have a master list of two arrays that are produced by different methods (batch_badge_creator and assign_rooms).

My problem is with the last section, the printer method. I need to output both methods on the screen, and print out each array item per array separately.

How can I iterate over the array of room assignments in order to puts out each individual assignment?

Thank you for your help!

```
def badge_maker(name)
"Hello, my name is #{name}."
end

attendees = ["Edsger", "Ada", "Charles", "Alan", "Grace", "Linus", "Matz"]

def batch_badge_creator(attendees)
  attendees.each {|x| badge_maker(x)}
  return badges 
end

def assign_rooms(room)
  room = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
  attendees.each_with_index {|x, index| "Hello #{attendees}! You will be assigned to room #{room}!"}
  return room_assignments
end

def printer(attendees)
  assign_rooms.each {|x| puts batch_badge_creator(assign_rooms)}
  puts badges_and_room_assignments
end
```

I need printer to put this:

```
Hello, my name is Edsger. 
Hello, my name is Ada. 
Hello, my name is Charles. 
Hello, my name is Alan. 
Hello, my name is Grace. 
Hello, my name is Linus. 
Hello, my name is Matz. 
Hello, Edsger! You'll be assigned to room 1! 
Hello, Ada! You'll be assigned to room 2! 
Hello, Charles! You'll be assigned to room 3! 
Hello, Alan! You'll be assigned to room 4! 
Hello, Grace! You'll be assigned to room 5! 
Hello, Linus! You'll be assigned to room 6! 
Hello, Matz! You'll be assigned to room 7!
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the end result you want?

Comment: @Jordan thanks, I learned about `<!-- language: lang-none -->` from your edit, used to improve the SO formatting in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've made some improvements but I think this is what you're after. Pay close attention to the variables beginning with `@`. These are instance variables which in short allow themselves to be *seen* by other methods within the same class. I've also put everything in a class and just some general tidying up and added some new bits. Hope it's useful.

```
class HotelEvent

  def badge_maker(name)
    "Hello, my name is #{name}."
  end

  def attendees
    @attendees = ["Edsger", "Ada", "Charles", "Alan", "Grace", "Linus", "Matz"]
  end

  def batch_badge_creator
    @badges = @attendees.map {|x| badge_maker(x)}
  end

  def assign_rooms
    @room_assignments = @attendees.map.with_index {|attendee, room| "Hello #{attendee}! You will be assigned to room #{room+1}!"}
  end

  def print_badges
    @badges.each {|b| puts b}
  end

  def print_room_numbers
    @room_assignments.each {|r| puts r}
  end

  def print_all
    print_badges
    print_room_numbers
  end  

end

new_event = HotelEvent.new
new_event.attendees
new_event.batch_badge_creator
new_event.assign_rooms
new_event.print_all
```

The output will be:

```
Hello, my name is Edsger.
Hello, my name is Ada.
Hello, my name is Charles.
Hello, my name is Alan.
Hello, my name is Grace.
Hello, my name is Linus.
Hello, my name is Matz.
Hello Edsger! You will be assigned to room 1!
Hello Ada! You will be assigned to room 2!
Hello Charles! You will be assigned to room 3!
Hello Alan! You will be assigned to room 4!
Hello Grace! You will be assigned to room 5!
Hello Linus! You will be assigned to room 6!
Hello Matz! You will be assigned to room 7!
```

Just edit and modify to your tastes! And bear in mind the code could still be much improved. For example by adding some setter methods, but I'll leave that for you as an exercise. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and time! This looks great. I like the way you modified it.

Comment: @LadyD. Glad to help. Just another tip, consider using the `initialize` method within your class. Have a look online to see what it does. Also if you found my answer or any other answer to be particularly useful, then please consider accepting by clicking the relevant grey tick so it turns green. And as part of the SO community, you should also do this for all your other questions:)